# How to remove Category quick filters?

Tags: magento-1.9

On my category filtered pages, this [page](https://www.arkellandwills.co.uk/sweaters.html) being an example. There are some filters at the top of the page.

[image]

`Sort by: 18` and `sort by position`.

These serve no real purpose and hence I'd like to remove them.

How can I remove these please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/{theme}/{name}/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

Then comment the bellow code:

**Limiter :**

```
    <div class="limiter text-left">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?php echo $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
    </div>
```

**Sort-by :**

```
<div class="sort-by">
    <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
    <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

There an other solution to remove that via **xml** but you remove all the toolbar, that said you will also lose the view type `grid/list`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution I**

Simply hide using below CSS

```
.category-products .limiter, .category-products .toolbar .sort-by {
    display: none;
}
```

**Solution II**

You can directly comment code on below file:

> app/design/frontend/[Package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

Comment: I consider this before but feel commenting out the code is just a bit more effective

Comment: No issue, But for this small design changes, I prefer CSS tweak :)